# Function on Date in R gives results as "NA"

Tags: r, date

My date value is in this format

```
02:27:16 05-Mar-2019, Tue stored in Assigned date column

Am converting
srdetails1$Assigned On GMT<-as.POSIXct(srdetails1$Assigned On GMT, tz="", format = "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y")
srdetails$Assigned On GMT
```

the value get converted as
43497.067407407405

Instead of showing a date and any function i use on this column for
 e.g :- 
**day(ymd_hms()** etc gives me **"NA**"

How do i resolve this - Any help appreciated

When i trim the date with only m/d/y (without time) it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Your format mask does not match the timestamp which you are trying to use with `as.POSIXct`.  Consider the following version:

```
x <- "02:27:16 05-Mar-2019"
as.POSIXct(x, tz="", format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")

[1] "2019-03-05 02:27:16 CET"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
addFormats("%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
anytime(x)
#[1] "2019-03-05 02:27:16 EST"
```

#### data

```
x <- "02:27:16 05-Mar-2019"
```